# Java do while, while

Tags: java, loops, do-while, ambiguity

what behaviour can I expect when I run this code:

```
do while(testA) {

    // do stuff

} while(testB);
```

Will it behave like:

```
do {
    while(testA) {
        // do stuff
    }    
} while(testB);
```

Or:

```
if(testA) {
    do {
        // do stuff
    } while(testA && testB);
}
```

Or something totally unexpected?

I ask this question because I think this is quite ambiguous, and for other people searching on this topic, *not* because I am lazy to test it out.

Comment: The behaviour you should expect is that a coworker hits you with a stick.

Comment: @voyager Luckily don't I have any coworkers to watch out for; thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is equivalent to your first block:

```
do {
    while(testA) {
        // do stuff
    }    
} while(testB);
```

The relevant parts of the [Java grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/19.doc.html#26499) when parsing this are:

```
DoStatement:
    do Statement while ( Expression ) ;

Statement:
    WhileStatement

WhileStatement:
    while ( Expression ) Statement

Statement:
    Block

Block:
    { BlockStatements_opt }
```

You can see that the Java compiler will parse this as `do <WhileStatement> while ( Expression ) ;`. That's the only valid way to parse the code that you wrote.

Keep in mind that it doesn't have any special rule to parse this construct. It just ends up being confusing for a human to read due to the unusual way the do-while loop is written. In normal usage do-while is always written as `do { ... } while` with explicit curly braces.

Answer (score 3):

It works indeed, but the behaviour depends on what conditions your are testing. E.g. this code:

```
  int i = 2;
  int j = 4;
  do while(j > 0) {
       i--; j--;
       System.out.println("i:" + i + " j:" + j);
 } while(i > 0);
```

outputs:

```
i:1 j:3
i:0 j:2
i:-1 j:1
i:-2 j:0
```

So it works like:

```
while(j>0) {

}
```

---

Whereas by exchanging the variable names:

```
do while(i > 0) {
    //.. same as above
 } while(j > 0);
```

The output is:

```
i:1 j:3
i:0 j:2
```

It looks like it behaves the same as in the first case (i.e. the first while is considered), but here, **the application is not terminating!**

---

**Summary:**
At the time when `testA` is **not satisfied** anymore and `testB` is also **not satisfied**, the code works like a normal `while(testA){}` loop.
**But:** If, at the time when `testA` is **no longer satisfied**, `testB` **is still satisfied**, the loop is **not** executed any more and the script is **not terminating**.  This only applies if the condition of the "outer" loop needs to be changed inside the loop.

**Update:**
And after reading other answer, I realize that this is exactly the behavior of the nested `do-while` - `while` loop.
Anyway, lesson learned: Don't use this kind of syntax because it can confuse you ;)

Comment: It's not terminating because once i reaches 0, the inner loop doesn't run anymore -- and therefore j can never reach 0.

Comment: Interesting, this obviously is because the outer `do while` loop will loop, but the content of this `do while` won't loop because the inner loop fails a condition! Thank you for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is #1. It will continue to loop as long as `testB` is satisfied but it will not execute the code if `testA` is not satisfied.

Comment: It is legal syntax (JDK 1.6). So why should it then be illegal code? Please explain.

Comment: You're right I've tested it and the answer is #1. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"`do {} while();`" is one construct, while "`while(){}`" is another.

There is no such thing as "`do while`"; you are inadvertently nesting them and taking advantage of the fact that {} is optional for single instructions.

In other words, this is legal syntax:

```
do System.out.println("Hello World") while (true);
```

And like in `if`-statements, a block is treated as a single statement.

Which is to say, your first possible answer is the right one, where "`while(){}`" is the single non-bracketed thing inside the outer "`do {} while();`"

Answer (score 1):

It behaves like

```
do {
    while(testA) { 
        // stuff
    }
} while(testB);
```

So, that block of code is parsed this way:

do {a block of code} while testB is true. Where {a block of code} is the inner while.

It's certainly a bit uncommon to write code like that :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this code is legal.

```
do while(testA) {

        // do stuff

    } while(testB);
```