# Double-condition while

Tags: java, while-loop, java-7

What does the following statement mean in Java?

```
while(condition_1) {
    do something...
} while (condition_2);
```

Is there any real-world situation to use it?

UPDATE: code example

```
    int i = 3;
    while (i < 10) {
        System.out.println(i++);
    } while (i < 15);
```

Comment: Please show compilable code when asking about code. Or start comments in front of `do something ...`

Comment: Please post real code.

Comment: That looks like an infinite loop to me... The value of `i` never changes after breaking out of the first while loop. This question is senseless in its current state.

Comment: A solo  `;` is an empty statement.

Comment: Please show real code. This is not meaningfull.

Comment: So many downvoters while person just want to understand what it used for. How you can ask the real code sample if he asks for **"Is there any real-world situation to use it?"** What if he asked about "foreach" purpose? Did you ask then for real code too?

Comment: @maythesource.com The UPDATE has the code.

Comment: just several statements formatted badly, its just two while-s man

Comment: @kosmos - One code sample does not compile. The other is an infinite loop.

Comment: @jahroy - He just wanted to understand what that statement means. I guess he don't know that you can write even single line code, so he got confused, but others started to ask for real code, which is impossible to show for non existent "rare" double while statement.

Comment: @anfy2002us - Maybe this is just kind of programming task where teaches asked him to explain what this code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second while is making your code sample to go in an infinite loop. for better understanding of do-while please go through the example mentioned here :
    [Java do while, while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434541/java-do-while-while)

Answer (score 10):

It's just 2 while statements. There is no significance to the second while being on the same line as the closing bracket of the first while loop. Whitespace, for the most part, doesn't matter. Your code would do the same thing if there were blank lines between the two while statements.

Edit: since you edited your code to include an empty while loop, you should notice that your second while loop doesn't actually do anything other than loop. So if you loop once, you'll be looping forever. You might be confusing this with a do-while loop, in which case you should consult the tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: So it prints 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9, and then iterates forever.

Comment: Completely right explanation it seems. Also, I feel this is mostly bad practice. Why have a while that does not do anything except maybe through inside the parenthesis. OP should have posted real code.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't looks for me any different from:

```
int i = 3;
while (i < 10) //loop that ends once i == 10
    System.out.println(i++);

while (i < 15) //infinite loop
    ; //that does nothing
```

There are just two while loops and badly formatted code.